# rendering the US unit separator on unix machine

Tags: java, bash, unix, ascii

I have a java application that feeds a file on a unix machine, each string contains multiple US unit separators,
Locally, when i run it on eclipse on a windows machine, it displays fine on the console:

```
1▼somedata▼somedata▼0▼635064▼0▼somedata▼6
```

But when i run the program from the unix machine, the content of the file appears as.

```
1â¼N/Aâ¼somedataoâ¼somedataâ¼somedata
```

Changing the LANG variable to any value in `locale -a` seems not to work.

Comment: How are you "changing the LANG variable"?

Comment: US is a control character. There is no visual representation defined for it.

Comment: @chrylis `export LANG=value`

Comment: Are you sure you have your terminal program itself set properly? Konsole, for example, has an encoding option on the View menu.

Comment: The black triangle is `U+25BC`, BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE. Its UTF-8 representation is `E2 96 BC`. Treating each byte as ISO 8859 (the character set apparently used by your terminal), `E2` is `â`, `96` is undefined (and seemingly unprinted), and `BC` is `¼`. In other words, your code is using a particular Unicode character (not ASCII 0x1f, unit separator), which is written in UTF-8 per your locale, but your terminal displays byte-by-byte rather than understanding UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

looks like character set mismatch. On linux you most probably have UTF-8. With Java you usually get UTF-16. Try converting from UTF16 to UTF8 with `iconv` and see how it looks like on linux.

```
cat file | iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8
```

But actually it would have been much worse if it was UTF-16. Maybe it is simply a font mismatch. But you can play with character encoding (see what source is and convert to utf-8) if that's the issue. Or maybe your source is UTF-8 and destination - some local encoding.
This makes sense because your special character appears as 2 characters in the UNIX machine. Which means source is pretty much likely UTF-8 and UNIX is using an encoding where each byte is a single character.

Comment: Hi,I tried it but the result is exactly the same, indeed as you say, on my linux machine i have UTF-8 ` echo ${LANG} en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: @JBoy, it doesn't mean your terminal is UTF-8. `LANG` only tells programs what output is expected. You may make a simple test and throw at your terminal some multi-byte UTF-8 characters to see how they appear.
`iconv` is good because it actually changes character set of the byte stream so you need to match `iconv` `to` encoding to what your terminal expects. Changing `LANG` cannot affect your running terminal in any way.